# Unable to see the data sent from STM32 over virtual COM port to PC

Tags: c, embedded, port, stm32f4, stm32cubeide

I am trying to learn STM32 programming and trying to send a sample text from the microcontroller to the PC. Here is the code :

```
#include "main.h"
\#include "usb_device.h"

/\* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
\#include "usbd_cdc_if.h"
\#include "string.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes \*/

/\* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD \*/

/\* USER CODE END PTD \*/

/\* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD \*/

/\* USER CODE END PD \*/

/\* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM \*/

/\* USER CODE END PM \*/

/\* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------\*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/\* USER CODE BEGIN PV \*/

/\* USER CODE END PV \*/

/\* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP \*/

/\* USER CODE END PFP \*/

/\* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 \*/

/\* USER CODE END 0 \*/

/\*\*

* @brief  The application entry point.
* @retval int
  */
  int main(void)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 \*/
  //const char txData ="HEllO";

/\* USER CODE END 1 \*/

/\* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------\*/

/\* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. \*/
HAL_Init();

/\* USER CODE BEGIN Init \*/

/\* USER CODE END Init \*/

/\* Configure the system clock \*/
SystemClock_Config();

/\* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit \*/

/\* USER CODE END SysInit \*/

/\* Initialize all configured peripherals */
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_USART2_UART_Init();
MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 \*/

/\* USER CODE END 2 \*/

/\* Infinite loop */
/* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE \*/
while (1)
{
char buffer\[\] = "Hello, World!\\r\\n";
//    CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t \*)txData, strlen(txData));
CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t *)buffer, sizeof(buffer));
HAL_Delay(1000);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, SET);
HAL_Delay(100);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, RESET);
/* USER CODE END WHILE \*/

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

}
/\* USER CODE END 3 \*/
}
```

I have also installed the virtual COM port driver and I can see it in the device manager.

Also, I have tried using different third -party softwares for serial data viewer, yet, I cannot see the data on the screen.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why have you escaped sharps and asterisks?

Comment: Please edit the code and remove everything commented 'begin...end` that has no content. There only seems to be about a dozen active lines of code in this unreadable post.

Comment: @WeatherVane Those are inserted by CubeIDE because this is auto-generated code. You can insert your own custom code inside the "begin...end" blocks, and those bits are retained if it has to re-generate the file (because you changed some peripheral config). Seems harsh to ask for their removal - anyone who works with STM32CubeIDE knows this structure.

Comment: @pmacfarlane it might be exact but is not mimimal.

Comment: While editing your code to remove the weird backslashes (and possibly the content-free comments), can you include the code that configures the USB peripheral?

Comment: Your code relies on a huge amount of generated code from STM32Cube.  It is critical that you have configured that appropriately for your hardware, but we have no sight of that.  Critically the USB clock must be 48MHz for example.

Comment: in USB_DEVICE\App\usbd_cdc_if.c, function CDC_Receive_FS:
See that the data received with 'USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);' is properly taken care of.
I usually modify the code in CDC_Receive_FS to store the data from 'Buf' in my own fifo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the latest code, or if the project even worked when I last changed it, but to give you an impression how I handled the USB data.

in a header file:

```
#define FIFO_SIZE 64 // must be 2^n  
#define FIFO_INCR(x) (((x)+1)&((FIFO_SIZE)-1))
#define FIFO_ISEMPTY(x) (x.head==x.tail)
#define FIFO_PUT(x,c) RX_FIFO.data[RX_FIFO.head] = c; RX_FIFO.head = FIFO_INCR( RX_FIFO.head );
#define FIFO_GET(x) RX_FIFO.data[RX_FIFO.tail]; RX_FIFO.tail = FIFO_INCR( RX_FIFO.tail );

/* Structure of FIFO*/
typedef struct FIFO {
    volatile uint32_t head;
    volatile uint32_t tail;
    volatile uint8_t data[FIFO_SIZE];
} FIFO;
extern FIFO RX_FIFO;
```

In usbd_cdc_if.c:

```
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS( uint8_t *Buf, uint32_t *Len ) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
    //// original contents:
    //// USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
    //// USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
    //// return (USBD_OK);
    uint32_t len = *Len;
    if( hUsbDeviceFS.dev_state != USBD_STATE_CONFIGURED ) {
        return USBD_FAIL;
    }
    if( ( ( Buf == NULL ) || ( Len == NULL ) ) || ( *Len <= 0 ) ) {
        return USBD_FAIL;
    }
    /* Get data */
    uint8_t result = USBD_OK;
    do {
        result = USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer( &hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0] );
    } while( result != USBD_OK );
    do {
        result = USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket( &hUsbDeviceFS );
    } while( result != USBD_OK );
    while( len-- ) // add data to FIFO
        if( FIFO_INCR(RX_FIFO.head) == RX_FIFO.tail )
            return USBD_FAIL; // overrun
        else {
            RX_FIFO.data[RX_FIFO.head] = *Buf++;
            RX_FIFO.head = FIFO_INCR( RX_FIFO.head );
        }
    return ( USBD_OK );
    /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
```

To send the data:

```
void your_own_send_function() {
    uint8_t buf[BUFMAX];
    // fill buf here
    // ... 
    // testing for STM32 USB device ready (don't care whether some packages are dropped or not)
    extern USBD_HandleTypeDef hUsbDeviceFS;
    USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *hcdc = (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*) hUsbDeviceFS.pClassData;
    if( hcdc != NULL ) { // Is the device INITIALISED
        if( hcdc->TxState == 0 ) { // Is the device NOT BUSY
            CDC_Transmit_FS( (uint8_t*) buf, p ); // send the buffer to the stm32 virtual serial port
            while( hcdc->TxState != 0 ) { // Wait max. 1000ms for the transmission to complete
                HAL_Delay( 20 );
                int teller = 0;           // CDC_Transmit_FS is non blocking, so...
                if( ++teller >= 50 ) {    // buf is located on the stack and will be deleted on return
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else { // USB BUSY, so drop the packet en toggle the LED
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin( GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2 );
        }
    }
}
```

It is important to wait until transmission is completed when you send a local variable. The code is running faster than USB transmission and the local variable might be cleared from the stack (and the space overwritten) before the package is sent!

This is how I configured the USB virtual serial port:
[image]
[image]